# Grails 3 fields plugin generating form elements from a command object

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-3.0

I am running grails 3.0.4 and I have a simple command object `AdvanceCommand`
I am trying to create a form for all the fields in the command object using `f:all` tag from fields plugin. But I get an error

```
[views/advance/create.gsp:35] [views/advance/create.gsp:30] Tag [all] currently only supports domain types
```

the [documentation](http://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/introduction.html) specifically mentions command objects so I am a bit confused. if this tag is not working how do I generate form elements for a command object?

This is a snippet from my controller

```
def create() {
    respond new AdvanceCommand()
}
```

and this is my gsp

```
        <g:form action="save">
            <fieldset class="form">
                <f:all bean="advanceCommand"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
```

**PS** in the source repo of field plugin the latest version is 1.5.1 but if I run plugin-info I get 2.0.3 and 1.5.x is not even mentioned. Am I using a different plugin ?

```
grails> plugin-info fields
| Plugin Info: fields
| Latest Version: 2.0.3
| All Versions: 2.0.0.M1,2.0.0,2.0.1,2.0.2,2.0.3
| Title: Fields Plugin

Customizable form-field rendering based on overrideable GSP template

* License: APACHE
* Documentation: https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields
* Issue Tracker: https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/issues
* Source: https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears they have forked a fields plugin from 1.4 to support grails 3. New [documentation](http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/guide/single.html#introduction) and [source repo](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields).

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/fields/issues/7) to support non domain objects in `<f:all>`. so it looks like its not supported yet. Using `<f:field>` seems to be the only way out